# how to intercept any php actions before execution

Tags: php, zend-framework2, interceptor

I want to intercept all PHP actions before execution that are targeting the file system or a DBMS.

Is there a way to do this only using PHP (and how would I do it?) or do I need to work within something like Zend?

Comment: You want to intercept all php actions, using php? That seems a bit contradictory.

Comment: I might seem stupid now, but I don't really get what exactly do you ask for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question so hopefully it's slightly more clear what you are asking for, but the question is still very broad and ambiguous.

Comment: For example, why would i allow your code to intercept all my application DBMS access? What would i gain by doing that?

Comment: I want to develop a security engine that intercepts all PHP actions that try to read, write, or update the file system or the databases.
After deep search in the internet, I found that it might be possible by developing a Zend module or a php module (using C). The closest part in PHP that could solve my problem is the Zend controller. But I don't know if I'm correct and I don't know how to do this.